# A way to import data for each time (ticks) in netlogo?

Tags: csv, import, netlogo

I have started using netlogo just some months and I am not professional in it,I want to import some time series data such as x, y and z for each ticks during simulation. I need an answer of how to import these data from a excel file that was converted to csv file and have 3 columns and 30 rows that each columns are related to x, y and z and each rows are related to different years and i want to use each year for each ticks for example, first row should be used in ticks 0, 2nd in tick 2 and to the end that 30th year for tick 29.
the name of file for these data is: data.csv

Comment: Have you tried using the CSV extension that comes with NetLogo 5.2? Try taking this at a step a time — first just see if you can write code that reads in the values and prints them. Then worry about incorporating that code into a simulation. Come here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Seth mentioned, the CSV extension can help with this. The [CSV extension documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html) has example code that you will probably find quite useful (see the section "Read a file one line per tick").